# LINQ with left outer join and group by SUM

Tags: linq, left-join

In my DTO i have invoice list and receipt list. I need to bind the invoices in the drop down list. For this i have the following conditions

I need to bind all the invoices with the total amount of that invoice receipts is less than the invoice value

My Invoice entity have ID, Number, Amount
My Receipt entry have ID, InvoiceID, Amount

I need to group the receipt list with invoice id and sum of the receipt amount must be less than Amount of that invoice list. How can i use linq or lamda doe this

Comment: I did like below. Its worked the problem in this approach is not getting invoices if not have any receipt against it                                                               var groupedReceipts = _receipts.ReceiptList.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceID).Select(g => new {g.Key, AmountPaid = g.Sum(x => x.Amount) }).ToList();

                var source = groupedReceipts.SelectMany(B => _receipts.InvoiceList.Where(A => B.Key == A.ID && B.AmountPaid < A.Amount)).ToList();

Comment: I did like below. Its worked the problem in this approach is not getting invoices if not have any receipt against it                  `var groupedReceipts = _receipts.ReceiptList.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceID).Select(g => new {g.Key, AmountPaid = g.Sum(x => x.Amount) }).ToList();

                var source = groupedReceipts.SelectMany(B => _receipts.InvoiceList.Where(A => B.Key == A.ID && B.AmountPaid < A.Amount)).ToList();`

Comment: Am I understanding that you do want invoices with no receipts? if so the query I posted should work, you'll just need to modify the last projection to get the format you'd like.

Comment: yes i am looking in to that. I also need to add 'select' in the first index to the result anonymous type. I think its fine will check all scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you need as the output but the join should look something like this...

```
    Invoices
      .GroupJoin(Receipts, 
          r => r.ID, 
          i => i.InvoiceID, 
          (i, ir) => new {
              i.ID, 
              i.Number, 
              Amount= i.Amount, 
              RAmount = ir.Sum(r => r.Amount)}) 
    .Where(i => i.RAmount < i.Amount)
    .Select(i => new {i.Number,i.ID}) //Project however you want to get your list item
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot. Can you please give any good article link to study this concept. Actually i didn't got the logic so only

Comment: No Problem - really glad that helped. I'm not sure of a good online tutuorial but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397941.aspx may be a good place to start. Essentially group join lets you combine your lists in a hierarchical   way and then project into a new object like you'd do with a select. I specify my lists - in this case I'm joining receipts to invoices... I then specify my primary key and foreign key. The final argument is essentially just a function that accepts an invoice and a list of receipts and outputs whatever type you'd like.